# Were pandavas and kauravas reborn after their death?

Tags: mahabharata

If yes means what were they born as?  Somewhere I heard that Arjuna reincarnated as kannappa nayanar in Kali yuga. Whether this is true? I want to know about the rebirth of all pandavas and kauravas. Not just Arjuna.

Comment: You can ask separate questions about the kauravas. Also since they are many u have to be specific.

Comment: @Rickross Even if he ask about Kauravas, i think it's impossible to find next births of all Kauravas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Ok. But what  if the Q is on someone specific?